# How to determine which part of the pattern has match in Regex

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I have a following pattern rather complex:

```
^(?=.*\b(?:averages?|standard|means?)\b)(?=.*\b(?:goods?)\b)(?=.*\b(?:costs|cost to the company|sold by vendors?|bought from vandors?)\b).*$
```

and its very nicely matching the following sentences:

1. What is average goods costs.
2. give me a standard list of goods bought from vendors.
3. list all standard goods sold by vendors.

I have to remove the matched pattern part from sentences i.e.

1. what is **__ list of _______**.
2. give me **________** for **______**.
3. list all **_____________**.

I am trying to split the pattern and thinking of performing match for every split instance of the pattern but its daunting so looking for a alternative solution thanks.

I trying to get the following to work.

```
string[] splitPat = value.Split(new string[] { ")(" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the pieces you want to be able to extract into groups by wrapping them in an extra set of `()`. For example:

```
^(?=.*\b((?:averages?|standard|means?))\b)(?=.*\b((?:goods?))\b)(?=.*\b((?:costs|cost to the company|sold by vendors?|bought from vandors?))\b).*$
```

When matching this string:

```
What is average goods costs.
```

`average`, `goods` and `costs` become the first, second and third group in your match.

Try playing with it here:

http://rubular.com/r/urb1raJ3W7

You can try different test strings and see what groups it will extract.

Then in .NET you can use [Match.Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups) to access the groups in a match. You can even name the groups if you want for easier maintanence.

Comment: Thanks Matt, but how would right the code to get the matched group word i.e. average from 1st group and goods from 2nd. Also the problem I have is that patterns list contain over 300 different but similar patterns I will have to restructure the full list.

Comment: @kashif4u: See the MSDN link I included in my answer. There is a very good example of extracting groups there.